# how to express this xaml combobox data-binding in c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, data-binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource stringResources}, Path=MyProp}"
```

I tried and got so far but I don't get it compiled:

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = new Binding { Source = new StringResources(), ElementName = "MyProp" };
comboBox.DisplayMemberPath="Value";
comboBox.SelectedValuePath="Key";
```

It says that it cannot convert Binding to IEnumerable and I wasn't sure how to construct a PropertyPath so I used ElementName but I don't know if this is the same.

StringResources is a class which has a property MyProp which returns a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var binding = new Binding("MyProp") { Source = new StringResources() };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(comboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

As an alternative to using `BindingOperations`, you could also use the [`SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setbinding.aspx) method on the `ComboBox` class.

In the interests of teaching you how to fish, your code was trying to assign the `Binding` instance directly to the `ItemsSource` property (which only takes objects of certain types, including `IEnumerable`). You need to use WPF's binding engine to translate your source into something that the target property can consume. In this case, it's translating or surfacing the `MyProp` property on an instance of `StringResources` to an enumeration that is then consumed by the `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: Thanks it works great now! I also noticed that it is very important to assign DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath *before* the binding is added, otherwise it won't work.